# Refresh token in RGoogleAnalytics

Tags: r, google-analytics, rgoogleanalytics

I'm trying to get data from my `GA` account using `R`. I've managed to do this with `RGoogleAnalytics` package. Unfortunetally I have a problem with authentication on production server. Everything works but I have to refresh token each day (and it is not acceptable for me). I've read about need of `refresh_token` but I have no idea how to obtain it using this package... What I did is:

```
    library("RGoogleAnalytics")
    
    client.id <- "XXX"
    client.secret <- "XXX"
    token <- Auth(client.id, client.secret)
    save(token, file = "./auth/token")
    
    load("./auth/token")
    ValidateToken(token)
```

It works only for few hours (when token is valid) and the next day I get the error: `Error: Refresh token not available`. How to get this refresh token? `Auth` function does not seem to give it to me and after reading whole Internet I still have no idea how to deal with it. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

the RGoogleAnalytics package gives an easy way to extract the Google Analytics Data. but I think you should consider other packages that are more up to date and that are a little bit 'easier' to deal with(like the [googleAnalyticsR](http://%20https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleAnalyticsR/googleAnalyticsR.pdf) package)

In my experience, practically all google services need this 'authentication' when using the API, and generally, the token expires, however, it is possible to generate a 'permanent token'.

This form for this 'permanent token' is a little 'hard', but once learned, you will be able to apply it in a similar way to most of Google's API services!

In summary, you need to create a project there in the GCP (Google Cloud console) to create an authentication key :

I recommend reading this first:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

In the documentation link below, you can find a step by step for this authentication for the RgoogleAnalytics package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGoogleAnalytics/RGoogleAnalytics.pdf